How to calculate translateX in a hexagon made of arrows
I created a hexagon made by six arrows using html and css, I want to stick the arrows together without gaps.
The 37% in translate(37%, -25%) is derived using the exhaustive method, and its not precise.
How can I actually calculate the translateX number correctly?
I am happy to accept answer that require the use of JavaScript or any helpful hints.


body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: navy;
  width: 55%;
  height: 48%;
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -100%;
  transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 6 * var(--i))) translate(37%, -25%);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 25% 50%);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 0"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 1"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 2"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 3"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 4"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 5"></div>
</div>




You can use decimal points for bigger precision, like translate(37.95%, -25%)

@Justinas But can I calculate that number?

But what exactly you want to achieve? To have uniform gaps between arrows?

@Justinas No, I want to stick the arrows together without gaps.

I know I can get a number with decimal by exhaustive method to achieve the result, but I want to actually calculate the number.

See, since your arrows has dynamic width and height, their corner angle will depend on width/height ratio. Can you just simply place all arrows with pre-defined dimensions?

Here is a slightly different way to code it using accurate values and math. All you have to do is to update one value.


body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 350px; /* you only have to adjust this */
  aspect-ratio: 1/cos(30deg);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.arrow {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  background-color: hsl(calc(60deg*var(--i)) 30% 60%);
  height: 40%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  --_d:(1 - 2*cos(30deg))/sin(30deg);
  transform: 
    rotate(calc(60deg*var(--i))) 
    translate(calc(50%*cos(30deg)), calc(25%*(var(--_d) - 1)));
  clip-path: 
    polygon(0 0,
     calc(100% - 50%*tan(30deg)) 0,100% 50%, 
     calc(100% - 50%*tan(30deg)) 100%,0 100%, 
     calc(       50%*tan(30deg)) 50%);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 0"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 1"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 2"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 3"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 4"></div>
  <div class="arrow" style="--i: 5"></div>
</div>




@Shuo I updated the code a little and removed the variable.
